# NestJs service can not find generated prisma orm module in NX monorepo in VSCode dev container

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma, vscode-devcontainer, nx-monorepo

For a while now I'm developing services inside a Visual Studio Code devcontainer with [NX](https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/why-monorepos) as a library for working with mono repos. For the database layer I'm using [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/) and use it to run migrations and generate the types to be used.

Lately the development container was giving issues to I did a clean rebuild on the container. After the install, I ran

```bash
for target in 'migrate generate-types'; do
    yarn nx run-many --target $target
done
```

`generate-types` is defined as the command `prisma generate` and `migrate` is `prisma generate dev`.

This will migrate all projects and generate all the files. Database is being migrated, types are present, so that works.

Everything is installed, all looks fine until I try to start the service. I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspaces/mono-repo/node_modules/@prisma/client/number'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1171:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:15)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:584:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:658:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Function.Module._load (/workspaces/mono-repo/node_modules/@nx/js/src/executors/node/node-with-require-overrides.js:18:31)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at Array.Object.defineProperty.value (/workspaces/mono-repo/dist/apps/numbering/main.js:266:18)
```

I found out that `yarn nx` runs the latest nx version, so I've updated the `packages.json` but the problem doesn't go away.

The directory `/workspaces/mono-repo/node_modules/@prisma/client/number` does contain files:

```
$ ls /workspaces/mono-repo/node_modules/@prisma/client/number
default.d.ts  edge.d.ts  index-browser.js  index.js                                      package.json  schema.prisma  wasm.js
default.js    edge.js    index.d.ts        libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node  runtime       wasm.d.ts
```

I did ran the migrate and generate types command more often before rebuilding the development container and that gave no issues. But suddenly after a `Rebuild without cache` the problem came up.

This is currently with every service that is using the Prisma ORM.

These are the packages that are loaded with `package.json`.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.17.0",
    "@bull-board/hapi": "^5.9.1",
    "@bull-board/koa": "^5.9.1",
    "@bull-board/ui": "^5.9.1",
    "@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq": "^4.0.0",
    "@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/bull": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/bullmq": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.1.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.2.8",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.2.8",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^10.2.8",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.2.8",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^3.0.4",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.8.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bull": "^4.12.2",
    "bullmq": "^5.1.3",
    "cache-manager": "^5.2.4",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cron": "2.4.4",
    "date-fns": "^3.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "minio": "^7.1.3",
    "nest-winston": "^1.9.4",
    "nestjs-minio": "^2.5.4",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.2",
    "slugify": "^1.6.6",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "winston": "^3.11.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.2.8",
    "@nx-tools/nx-prisma": "^5.1.0",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/jest": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/js": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/linter": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/nest": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/node": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/webpack": "17.3.1",
    "@nx/workspace": "17.3.1",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.6.7",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.104",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.8",
    "@types/mime-types": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/node": "~20.11.5",
    "@types/passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.40",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "~8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.7.0",
    "nx": "^17.3.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.4",
    "prisma": "^5.8.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  }
```

So in `packages.json` `nx` is still the previous version. As I said, an update of that didn't solve the problem.

Why does it say it's missing the module, even when there are files and what can I do to solve this?

Edit:
I've got a workaround now:

- Added to `paths` in `tsconfig.base.json`: `"@database/number": ["node_modules/@prisma/client/number"]`
- Changed `export { Prisma } from '@prisma/client/number';` to `export { Prisma } from '@database/number';` where the errors occurred.

When I do this, the application starts. Why this works and the original doesn't I don't know.